# History of 11 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)100,000 Jews of Sicily Italy were expelled in 1491

2)The Jews of Mezhibuzch where saved from a Pogrom by the Cossacks during *Gezairas Tach Vtat*
became known as the Purim of Mezhibuzch in 1647

3)The Jews where expelled from Austria in 1667

4)Yahrtzeits

-Mechaber Arugas Habosem (1784)

-Shlomo Eiger Mechaber of the Gilyon Marasha (1851)

-Rav Yeshuah of Dzikov Mechaber of Ateres Yeshoshua (1912)